# \textbf and \textit does not work

Tags: bold, italic

So I have a main.tex that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[danish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
   %\cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
}
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\title{\Huge \textbf{De Maskerede}}
\author{\textsc{Niklas}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

{\fontfamily{times}\selectfont
\chapter{\textit{Prolog}}
\input{Prolog/Post.tex}

\end{document}
```

And my post.tex file looks like this:

```
hi this is \textbf{bold}
```

When I do a \textbf inside the main.tex it works (like the \title), but when I do a \textbf in one of the input files (like \input{Prolog/Post.tex}), it does not work. I can't figure out the reason why.

Best regards
Niklas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Currently your question is difficult to answer, because we don't know the contents of your `Post.tex` file. Other relevant information that changes the behavior of your document may be inside `commands.tex`, which is also unknown. It would therefore be helpful if you could either provide the contents of those files, but even better if you could reduce the code of those files and your main file to the minimum code that still reproduces the issue, and edit your question to show this minimal code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have removed the commands.tex and tried just a simple line in the post.tex - I have tried removing the irrelevant stuff

Comment: You can replace that `\input` with just the contents of that file, it does not make any difference

Comment: I get ```Font shape `T1/times/m/n' undefined``` and related warnings with your code which explains the problems you're having. It is strange that you're doing `\fontfamily{times}\selectfont` after you loaded `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Maybe remove both and load `\usepackage{newtxtext}` for a times-like font.

Comment: There is no font family called times as you will see from the log. Additionally, if the base language here is suppose to be `danish` then make sure it is loaded as the last option to `babel` not the first

Comment: I'm using overleaf, and I did not get any warnings. But thank you very much! It was the "times" that caused the issue - Removed it, and now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Niklas you get them on Overleaf as well. Open the log file and have a look.

Answer (score 10):

You can reproduce exactly the same issue with the following minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{times}\selectfont

\textbf{bold}

\textit{italic}

\end{document}
```

Upon running LaTeX on it, you'll be greeted with some warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/times/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/times/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/times/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/times/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/times/m/n' instead on input line 9.
```

The first one means that LaTeX doesn't know about a `times` font family and does the default substitution for it, namely with the `cmr` font family.

The other two warnings are related to the same issue. LaTeX *has* defined a font corresponding to `OT1/times/m/n` but just as an alias to a fixed substitution font and hasn't set up the whole font family, because it knows nothing about it. So the subsequent font substitutions can only point to the only known font.

If you want to typeset your document in a Times clone, add

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

to your document preamble.